# What is the mean of this exponential random variable?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, nakagami-distribution

I have read a paper that says that the following is exponentially distributed

$$ Y=  \bigl| \sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i^{-\frac{1}{2}} h_i \bigl|^2$$

where $\gamma_i$ are non-negative constants and

$$h_i \sim \mathcal{CN} (0,1)\,,$$

where $\mathcal{CN}(\mu,\Gamma)$ denotes a [circularly symmetric complex normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution#Circularly-symmetric_complex_normal_distribution) distribution.

The authors claim that the mean of this exponential distributed $Y$ is $$\sum_{i=1}^n{\gamma_i}^{-1}$$.

Does anyone know why?

My thoughts are the following

1- The sum of Gaussian is also Gaussian

2- Magnitude of Gaussian is Rayleigh distributed

3- Taking the square of Rayleigh is exponential

But how do we get that the mean ?

My second part of this question is

What happens if $$h_{i} \sim \text{Nakagami } m $$

Comment: @GLen_b complex normal

Comment: I am actually looking for two things, 1- Why is the mean $\sum_{i=1}^n \gamma^{-1}$ for the case of Normal Gaussian 2- What happens , what is the distribution of $Y$ if I redefine the $h_i$ to be Nakagami iid parameter m.

Comment: It says in the wiki page, it is usually denoted as... same way I write it above

Comment: this is circullary symmetric are you comfortable now?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to check .. are the $h_i$ meant to be independent of each other?

Comment: guess? they can be or maybe not

Comment: Reading the wikipedia entry, a Nakagami random variable appears to be real univariate, not complex.

Comment: So I would like to find the $\sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i^{-1/2}h_i$ ? if they are Nakagami

Comment: Where did you read that they can't be complex?

Comment: I didn't say 'can't be'. I refer to the definition given at the wikipedia page which as defined the is for a real univariate variable, rather than a complex one. If you want to define it for a complex variable, you'd need to give a complete definition of what the distribution of a complex-Nakagami variable is (a pdf, say).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just addressing the first part for now:

Your line of thinking about why it's exponential is essentially along the right lines, after small modifications to get some details correct (you'll need independence in your step 2 for example, to invoke the Rayleigh).

For constant $c_i$, I think we have that $c_i h_i \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,c_i^2I)$ (where here $\mathcal{CN}$ with two arguments refers to the circularly symmetric complex normal).

This along with linearity of expectation explains where the $\sum \gamma_i^{-1}$ comes from.

---

Answer to Q from comments:

> how does the scale parameter $γ^{−1}_i$ change the distribution of $|h_i|^2$?

If $h_i^2 \sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta)$ (where here I mean the shape-scale parameterization, not the shape-rate parameterization), then

$γ^{−1}_i\,h_i^2\sim\text{Gamma}(\alpha, γ^{−1}_i\beta)$.

(If you want the shape-rate parameterization, you multiply the rate parameter by $\gamma_i$)

Comment: I think our reasoning is correct then, do you happen to know what happens if those $h_i$ are Nakagami distrbuted ?

Comment: There's a reason I said "Just addressing the first part for now". I've heard of it but I need to go look it up.

Comment: I am not sure there is a closed form of the sum of Nakagami, I looked myself. I think convolution is the way to go if one assumes the summand are independent.

Comment: It appears to be a scaled chi distribution. Okay -- I also don't think linear combinations of such variables are going to have a simple closed form.

Comment: I think for the Nakagami case, we can find the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i^{-1}|h_i|^2$ instead rather than $|\sum_{i=1}^n\gamma_i^{-\frac{1}{2}}h_{i}|^2$

Comment: If I had to find $\sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i^{-1}|h_i|^2$, then we have the sum of scaled Gamma distribution am I right @Glen_b

Comment: Well, to be clearer, you have a sum of scaled gamma random *variables* (you don't literally sum the distribution-functions); but if the scale parameters are not the same the distribution of this isn't simple in form. [note that, if $h_i$ is real, you don't really need the $|.|$ since you square it right after.]

Comment: Yes ofcourse you are right, Gamma random variables. I guess the next question would be how does the scale parameter $\gamma_i^{-1}$ change the distribution of $|h_i|^2$ (Gamma Random Variable ) right?

Comment: See my edited answer. Note that when you phrase it as "the distribution of $|h_i|^2$", you say "Gamma distribution". This time the phrasing describing the thing was different, meaning we were talking about the distribution this time, not the variable. It can be tricky to keep these straight, but it's important to do so (in other words, my pedantry is there for a reason).

Comment: Thanks but how did you obtain this result?

Comment: Because that's how scale parameters work; if $\theta$ is a scale parameter in a distribution for $X$, then $kX$ has scale $k\theta$. You could show it algebraically by considering the CDF, for example.

Answer (score 1):

A standard circularly symmetric complex normal random variable is
of the form $Z = X + iY$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent zero-mean
normal random variables with variance $\frac 12$. Here $i = \sqrt{-1}$.
We write $Z \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,1)$ and $X, Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\frac 12)$.
Note that $$E[|Z|^2] = E[X^2+Y^2]= \frac 12 + \frac 12 =1.$$
Note also that 
$|Z|^2$ is an exponential random variable with parameter (and hence mean)
equal to $1$.
From this, it is easy to deduce that $\sigma Z \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma^2)$
and that $|\sigma Z|^2$ is an exponential random variable with mean $\sigma^2$
and hence parameter $\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$.

Thus, since the $H_k$ are independent $\mathcal{CN}(0,1)$ random variables, meaning that $H_k = X_k + i Y_k$ where $X_k$ and $Y_k$ are independent 
$\mathcal N(0,\frac 12)$ random
variables, $\gamma_k^{-1/2}H_k$ is a
$\mathcal{CN}(0,\gamma_k^{-1})$ random variable, and so
$$Z = \sum_{k=1}^N \gamma_k^{-1/2}H_k = \sum_{k=1}^N\gamma_k^{-1/2}(X_k+iY_k)
= \bar{X} + i\bar{Y} \sim \mathcal{CN}\left(0,\sum_k \gamma_k^{-1}\right).$$
It follows that $|Z|^2 = \displaystyle \left|\sum_{k=1}^N \gamma_k^{-1/2}H_k\right|$ 
is an exponential random variable with mean $\sum_k \gamma_k^{-1}$.

About the only claim that does not follow from simple applications
of general rules is that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent zero-mean 
normal random variables with common variance $\frac 12\sigma^2$,
then $X^2+Y^2$ has an exponential distribution. Note that
the usual method changing to polar coordinates gives
$$P\{X^2+Y^2 > z\}
=\int_{\sqrt{z}}^\infty \int_0^{2\pi}
 \frac{1}{\pi\sigma^2} r\exp(-r^2/\sigma^2) \,\mathrm d\theta \, \mathrm dr
= \exp(-z/\sigma^2)$$
showing that $X^2+Y^2$ has an exponential distribution with parameter
$\sigma^{-2}$ and hence mean $\sigma^2$.